# Storing 512 Byte Arrays in a MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

So I'm trying to store a hash and salt. The code that generates the hash and salt looks like this:

```
from pbkdf2.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2
import os
salt = os.urandom(64)    # 512-bit salt
hash = PBKDF2(password, salt).read(64) # 512-bit key
```

This gives me some bytes of 512 length. However, when I try and store them into a mysql database I run into some trouble. I think the python 2.7 solution is

```
salt.encode('utf-8')
hash.encode('utf-8')
```

but that doesn't work for python3. I'm currently trying

```
"'"+salt.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')+"', '"+hash.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')+"'"
```

in my insert string, but I get the error:

> latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u06e0' in position 158:
>   ordinal not in range(256)

Any ideas on how to store bytes in a mysql database?

EDIT: I've tried using both varchar(512) and blob(512)

Comment: can you add the full query code?

Comment: `BLOB` should work. In [converters.py](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/converters.py), `escape_bytes` uses `binascii.hexlify` to create a [hexadecimal literal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/hexadecimal-literals.html).

Comment: Nice find eryksun. Want to make a formal response so I can mark that as the correct answer?